# HPE J9265A 6600-24XG switches & java for the web interface?

Tags: java, switch, hpe

Does the latest firmware for HPE J9265A 6600-24XG switches still require java for the web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the old release notes (PDF, page 16)](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02566147), your switch stopped requiring Java in software version `K.15.01.0031` which was released in May 2010.

As of this writing, the most recent software version for this switch is [`K.15.18.0021`](https://asp.arubanetworks.com/downloads/software/RmlsZTowY2IzMWZkYy0zZjc0LTExZTktODVmYi1iYjU2MTE5ZDI2ZWQ%3D) which was released in March 2019.

Comment: Any idea of where I can find the older firmware? Per the release notes for  k.15.18.0021 I need to upgrade in steps. k.13.68 and k.12.62 are no longer posted on the HPE web site?

Comment: @JPoole You probably need to contact HPE support and see if they can help you. The K.15 and K.14 releases are all [here](https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9265A&lang=&cc=&prodSeriesId=), but older ones are not. HPE actually [has a document for a different model that uses the same software](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02944873) that says you need to ask tech support for the older ones.